# Continuing abrupted dist-upgrade or enabling SSH in recovery mode

Tags: 16.04, server, upgrade, recovery-mode, 19.04

I accidentally cancelled the dist-upgrade of my 16.04 Ubuntu Server.
The server will now not boot into normal Ubuntu but instead into (I think) recovery mode. As the server is hosted I can't really confirm that.

Now to my question: Is it somehow possible to get out of the recovery remotely or continue the cancelled upgrade?

My hoster offers a recovery debian image in RAM if that can be used in any way.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get into a terminal try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then  `sudo apt install -f` **check the packages changed** make sure it doesn't remove something important

Answer (score 0):

You can try boot in recovery mode, mounting your system root partition in a directory and run bash chroot on that directory. From there, you can inspect and try to correct your system state.